# Customize the Speech Recognition Dialog

Tags: android, audio, dialog, speech-recognition, speech

I want to know if there is any way to change and customize the style of the Speech Recognition dialog in my app?

i.e.: change google logo or texts.
[image]

i use this code, is it complete?

```
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
     proccessTXT.setText("Speak now!");
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    proccessTXT.setText("Waiting");
}

@Override
public void onError(int error) {
     proccessTXT.setText(R.string.toast_disconnect);
}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        match_text_dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        match_text_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_maches_flag);
        match_text_dialog.setTitle(R.string.selection_list);
        textlist = (ListView) match_text_dialog.findViewById(R.id.list);
        matches_text = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches_text);
        textlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        textlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                type_texts = matches_text.get(position);

                speech_text.append(type_texts + " ");

                match_text_dialog.hide();

                //  speech_text.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new SelectText());
                actionMode = MainActivity.this.startActionMode(new SelectText());
            }
        });
        match_text_dialog.show();// show dialog

}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

}
```

this is LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: PACKAGE, PID: 25645
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:502)
                                                                                    at PACKAGE.MainActivity.onResults(MainActivity.java:245)
                                                                                    at android.speech.SpeechRecognizer$InternalListener$1.handleMessage(SpeechRecognizer.java:456)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an option you can launch speech recognizer with `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` (without UI) and show whatever dialog you need

```
SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);
Intent speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
speechRecognizer.startListening(speechIntent);
```

Here you need to implement `RecognitionListener` so you can show the dialog in `public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)` callback. Dismiss in `public void onResults(Bundle results)` or `public void onError(int error)`

Comment: thaks. i use it. is it complete? because as i run it, it shows error method.

Comment: Don't forget to add the RECORD_AUDIO permission to your manifest and, if you're using a marshmallow device, [request permission](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) from the user.

Comment: @KhalidovOleg. i mean this string is shown.`public void onError(int error) {
     proccessTXT.setText(R.string.toast_disconnect);}` Does it cause of noy using the @Mchiyo permission?

Comment: @MinaDahesh do you mean you always get an error? what's error's value? And yes, as Michiyo said you need to add `RECORD_AUDIO` permission

Comment: @OlegKhalidov. i update my question with the log cats. as it want to run `public void onResults(Bundle results)` method, the app has been stopped.

Comment: @MinaDahesh Change `matches_text = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);` to `matches_text = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);`

Comment: I'll look in an hour or two. Anyway, fill free to vote up for my answer and accept it if it helped)

Comment: i do it. please you do too

Comment: @OlegKhalidov. did you see my question? would you help me?

Comment: @MinaDahesh I did, but I can't help you with that, sorry

Comment: @OlegKhalidov     hi can u explain how i can use customize dialog instead of using google provided dialog?? i m not getting your solution ...

Comment: i tried this code still google provided dialog is visible

Comment: Here's a working sample https://github.com/algolia/voice-overlay-android

Comment: @everyone add this to your intent
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "")

Answer (score 0):

```
//use this for implementing speech to text translation in android via java
micbtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        input.setText("");
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Device doesn't Support this Feature", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data ) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 1:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            ArrayList<String> info = data . getStringArrayListExtra (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            input.setText(info.get(0).replaceAll("\\s", "").toUpperCase());

        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add to manifest:

```
<queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox"/>
 </queries>
```

code:

```
SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);
Intent speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
speechRecognizer.startListening(speechIntent);
```